# winding number question

Tags: complex-analysis, operator-theory

This is part of a proof from Banach algebra techniques in Operator theory by Ronald Douglas on page 170.

Let $\epsilon>0$.  Let $T$ be the unit circle and $\phi\in H^\infty+C(T)$.  Choose $\psi\in H^\infty$ and a negative integer $N$ such that $\|\phi-\chi_N \psi\|_\infty<\frac{\epsilon}{3}$ where $\chi_N(e^{it})=e^{iNt}$.  Now $\psi=\psi_0\psi_i$ where $\psi_0$ is an outer function and $\psi_i$ is an inner function.  Then the book shows there exist $\delta_1>0$ such that for all $1-\delta_1<r<1$, $|\widehat{\chi_N\psi}(re^{it})-\widehat{\chi_n\psi_i}(re^{it})\widehat{\psi_0}(re^{it})|<\frac{\epsilon}{3}$.  Then the book states that this implies $n(\widehat{\chi_N\psi}(re^{it}),0)=n(\widehat{\chi_n\psi_i}(re^{it}),0)+n(\widehat{\psi_0}(re^{it}),0)$ where $n(f,0)$ is the winding number of $f$ at 0.

I am not seeing why $n(\widehat{\chi_N\psi}(re^{it}),0)=n(\widehat{\chi_n\psi_i}(re^{it}),0)+n(\widehat{\psi_0}(re^{it}),0)$ holds.

Here $\widehat{\phi}$ is the Gelfand transform of $\phi$.

Comment: @PavelM: I cleared the comments since the OP edited.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen: I cleared the comments since OP edited.

Comment: what is the hat operation in $\widehat{\chi_N\psi}$?